# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I want to run the below program,using the hadoop-3.0:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


public class HDFSFileTest {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    try {
        String fileName="input/test.txt";
        Configuration conf =new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://localhost:9000");
    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl","org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
        FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(conf);
        if(fs.exists(new Path(fileName))) {
            System.out.println("File exists!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File not exists!");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

But I get the exception when I execute the code in eclipse:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for 
more info.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2559)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3254)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3286)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3337)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3305)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:476)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:225)
at HDFSFileTest.main(HDFSFileTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not found
at
```

I have checked the package hadoop-common-3.0.1.jar, hadoop-hdfs-3.0.1.jar,and there is no such class called

```
 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the client core jar for the hadoop version and try running the code again. This sometimes occurs due to jar missing issue.

The second thing is that "fs.hdfs.impl" is deprecated.

You can have a look into :- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/32800/where-can-i-find-fshdfsimpl-property.html

Comment: i download the hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar from Maven Repository,however,its latest version was published in 2013,after importing the jar,there is a new exception:                                  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress`

Comment: Are you using hadoop or hadoop 2 ?  If you are using hadoop2 ,then you need to download hadoop client 2.8.3 jar.

Comment: No,i'm using hadoop 3.0.1,i imported all the jar with "hadoop-client",last error disappear, instead, a new exception: 
 `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$GetFileInfoRequestProto cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message`

Comment: It means you have included two different versions of hadoop inside the jar. You can remove the old dependency and it should work fine.

Comment: You mean that  I should remove some repeat jar or similar jar ?  I import the external jars directly using eclipse,what should I do to find where's the problem and remove the old dependency?

Comment: Check out the dependency for a Hadoop version you are using and remove any other old dependency jars.

Comment: I choose to use hadoop 2.7.5 instead 3.0.1， the problem solved,thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you guys just need to add some other jars.

I had the same problem before, then I happened to add some other jars like below. Luckily, I succeeded.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I needed to download (in gradle format):

```
implementation 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.2.1'
implementation 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:3.2.1'
implementation 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs-client:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

[FindJar](http://www.findjar.com/) tells me it's in Hadoop Core

http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem.html